# Reserve a space for alert message but the message is only placed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know to reserve a space I should use `visibility: hidden`. But in my case, I have `div` element that is basically empty.

```
<div class="text-center mb-3 msg" id="copy-msg">
</div>
```

And I'm using JS to place the message inside as below.

```
// Alert the copied text
document.getElementById("copy-msg").innerHTML = "Copied!";
```

But when the message appears, the other element is pushed down. How do I place the message without moving the other elements?

Comment: The div is empty, so it won't have any height. Put a `&nbsp;` in there as the initial value, then it will be as high as a line of text normally would.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! But it still gets pushed down in responsive mode, when the alert message takes two lines, instead of one. And if I place a `height` to allow for two liner, the element will move up in non-responsive mode, since it only uses one line of text.

Comment: give `min-height` to div in responsive mode

Comment: You could put the message in the div already, but give it the same color as the background, make it transparent, or set the opacity to zero. That way the text is not visible, but takes up the space it needs. Then when you want to show it, you just change it back to normal.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You're right as well.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware be careful of this approach and accessibility - screen readers will read out the text which will be very confusing for the user.

Comment: @Yogi Not really.

Comment: If the message content is dynamic and can run longer than one line depending on screen dimensions, then you should probably go look for something that "reveals" the message by having an element expand with some sort of transition/ animation; because if the message ever got so long that it would take ten lines to display on a mobile, it would probably not make much sense to keep ten "free" lines of space in the initial view, that's just wasting valuable screen real estate.

Comment: If this is really a sort of alert message, would the 'normal' approach of having it show over the rest of the screen be suitable, rather than trying to reserve space for messages that may be any length?

Comment: @AHaworth You right, but you can control what a screen reader reads with [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden). However, if the message isn't always the same this method is pointless.

Comment: @CBroe I get your point. But I was thinking of something simple since it's just a simple online tool. I actually only need two lines.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that's a really bad idea to use text color same as the background color etc. There's the `visibility: hidden;` which keeps the area intact but hides the element from screen readers. If you really wanted to push for that strange solution anyways. But that's exactly what OP already tried.

Comment: @AHaworth Having it "shown" like using visibility: hidden is an option. But I'm concerned over its effect on SEO. I'm not 100% certain if Google indexer reads CSS.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Copy-to-clipboard functionality and all you want is to show an on-screen notification?

Comment: The element definitely has to take up some space when you eventually render it and will the other elements down. You could position is absolutely to the parent element with ```position: absolute;```, so that it does not take up space in the parent element. Set the parent element to relative positioning first for this to work. Hope I understood your question very well...

Comment: What other elements?